# Is there a way to "preserve" results in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, memoization

I'm new to Haskell and understand that it is (basically) a pure functional language, which has the advantage that results to functions will not change across multiple evaluations. Given this, I'm puzzled by why I can't easily mark a function in such a way that its remembers the results of its first evaluation, and does not have to be evaluated again each time its value is required.

In [*Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), for example, there is a [simple idiom](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) for accomplishing this:

```
f[x_]:=f[x]= ...
```

but in Haskell, the closest things I've found is [something like](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization)

```
f' = (map f [0 ..] !!)
   where f 0 = ... 
         f n = f' ...
```

which in addition to being far less clear (and apparently limited to `Int` arguments?) does not (seem to) preserve results within an interactive session.

Admittedly (and clearly), I don't understand exactly what's going on here; but naively, it seems like Haskel should have some way, at the function definition level, of

- taking advantage of the fact that its functions are *functions* and skipping re-computation of their results once they have been computed, and
- indicating a desire to do this at the function definition level with a simple and clean idiom.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Haskell that I'm missing? I understand (sort of) that Haskell can't store the evaluations as "state", but why can't it simply (in effect) redefine evaluated functions to be their computed value?

---

This grows out of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/101851/37543), in which lack of this feature results in terrible performance.

Comment: GHC has decided that you would probably use too much memory if you remembered function application, and its probably right. It does remember constants though.

Comment: Another haskell implementation would be free to memoize functions if it pleased.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a suitable library, such as [MemoTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie).

```
import Data.MemoTrie

f' = memo f
 where f 0 = ... 
       f n = f' ...
```

That's hardly less nice than the Mathematica version, is it?

---

Regarding

> “why can't it simply (in effect) redefine evaluated functions to be their computed value?”

Well, it's not so easy in general. These values have to be stored somewhere. Even for an `Int`-valued function, you can't just allocate an array with all possible values – it wouldn't fit in memory. The list solution only works because Haskell is lazy and therefore allows infinite lists, but that's not particularly satisfying since lookup is *O*(*n*).
For other types it's simply hopeless – you'd need to somehow diagonalise an over-countably infinite domain.

You need some cleverer organisation. I don't know how Mathematica does this, but it probably uses a lot of “proprietary magic”. I wouldn't be so sure that it does really work the way you'd like, for any inputs.

Haskell fortunately has type classes, and these allow you to express exactly what a type needs in order to be quickly memoisable. [HasTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.2/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html#t:HasTrie) is such a class.

Comment: It probably isn't magic, it just remembers what is given to it.

Comment: @PyRulez: there's no such thing as “just remembering”, you need some sort of data structure. I suppose Mathematica uses a mutable hash map.

Comment: You can remember them in evaluation order. Only a finite number of evaluations are ever performed. See unsafememo.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about MemoTrie? How might I use to for example [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/101851/37543)?

Comment: This is exactly what gets usually done in python. You have a "decorator" (which is nothing than an higher order function that wraps a given function with the cache functionality) that keeps tracks of the results in a `dict` (a hashmap).

Comment: @PyRulez you mean like `map f [1..999999999999999999999999999999999]`, and then `f 999999999999` ? It would seem that memory is unfortunately more finite than the number of evaluations ....

Comment: @Ingo More like `force (map f [1..999999999999999999999999999999999])` and then `f 999999999999`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: [what do you mean](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.2/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html)?

Comment: Remember: "new to Haskell". I'm coming from a world where "docs" means something else, I guess. How, for example would I implement `g x y z :: String -> Int -> String -> Int` as a memo?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: you have `String -> Int -> String -> Int` and want another `String -> Int -> String -> Int` (with the property that each parameter be memoised). Clearly the particular types shouldn't matter, so the memoising-function should have a type of the form `(a->b->c->d) -> a->b->c->d`, or whatever else type variables. You look in the documentation, and see `memo3 :: (HasTrie r, HasTrie s, HasTrie t) => (r -> s -> t -> a) -> r -> s -> t -> a`.

Comment: That was assuming that you actually want to memoise every possible combination of parameters – note that this may require an infeasible amount of memory! Perhaps the expensive calculation only depends on the first `String` parameter? Then you can make it so only that part is memoised, by writing you function in the form `f str1 = \int str2 -> ...`, and using `memo` to memoise it.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. So the memoize a function with X arguments, I need to use (and there needs to be a) memoX in MemoTrie, right?

Comment: Yup, though in fact `memo3` is the highest they offer out of the box – but you can write any function of _n_ arguments as a function of a single tuple with _n_ fields. (That's basically what most other languages default to anyway; [just Haskell doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Which actually makes memoisation quite a bit nicer.)

Comment: And "That's hardly less nice than the Mathematica version, is it?" — It's very much less nice. It introduces introduces an additional function, `f'` that requires me that I need to remember to use (instead of `f`) when I want performance (either in my other code or, critically, in the definition of `f`. Things might be better of the names automatically had some systematic representation (e.g. if memoization of `f` aways created a function named `f'`.)

Comment: You _can't_ use `f` in other code: it's not visible, because defined locally in `f'`'s scope. In fact you don't need to define `f` at all: just write `f' = memo $ \n -> case n of ...`. Then you can't even use `f` withing `f'`, because it doesn't exist! However, if for some reason you want to evaluate the function in some cases _without_ memoisation, you can easily do that if there's both `f` and `f'`. — What's also nice about the Haskell way is that it doesn't require any built-in language support. This makes the compiler simpler, and often simpler means it can optimise more agressively.